# Vertica Overall

Tags: vertica

Hi all, my company and I are looking for a product that can give a hand in taking off some loads (big once) from OLTP databases! So we have stumbled on Vertica.
After some tests and studies for the last 2 months we have decided that we will hit our customers with our new product (is not our is Vertica's product). 
Well all good and nice until the license price hit in!! And as everybody know there are not to many databases that run on more than 5 TB or at least we don't have to many!! or maybe none !! 
Ok, so I will get to the point!! At what point does Vertica pays off!! And I would like to compare it with Oracle.
We all know Oracle license is yearly and is on top to core/proc/mem etc... ; Vertica on the other side it's license costs is up to TB use and I will bold this ROW DATA is not compressed data.

So the question is: **At what point (database size) would Vertica will be a good choice?**

This point can be let's say a 5 TB database using for 5 year Vertica will bring you a benefit of XXX % in comparing it with ORACLE or SQL SERVER. 
Good to remember Vertica has it support service at 21 % of total license purchase price. I mean no offense to any of the company's cited in this text nor i am trying to promote none of them!! I am just looking for an opinion and please if any of my statements are wrong fell free to correct me.
I have no doubts that there are companies that implemented Vertica and done their market studies along with strong bench-marking tests, so fell free to share the knowledge.
As well I know this is such a general question with so many answers and opinions, all of them are welcomed!! 
Thank you all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In past examinations, Vertica does well because you can compress data and you can use commodity hardware so 5 TB on-disk with Vertica is not equivalent to 5 TB on-disk with Oracle.

First, it's not just cost but speed. If you need speed, Vertica is a better option than Oracle/SQL Server. But to figure out cost, you also need to figure out if your 10 TB Oracle database will actually be a 5-7 TB Vertica database.

Compression levels will vary depending on what your data looks like, so you'll want to run some tests, with Vertica's help, to figure out what those compression levels will look like.

Feel free to message me privately as well.

Comment: Quota is measured on UNCOMPRESSED data. So, it's not about how much it is on disk. Export the data to TSV (don't exclude views / projections), get the file-size, and that's approximately your usage.

Comment: @TimHarper Not sure I understand the views / projections part of your comment as views are just SQL on top of projections (no data stored) and well... I am pretty sure Vertica does not charge license costs using all projections created, only a single super-projection for each table.

Comment: You're correct; I meant to say don't INCLUDE views, not don't exclude views. (the double negative was not intended).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Oracle is alternative for your 5T use case unless you consider Oracle Exadata (Same for SQLserver ) , Exadata should be much more expensive (same for the sql server big data solution .

One comment about commodity server , to get the maximum performance commodity servers will not be enough , vertica very like big memory address space and many cores .

About 20% extra each year for support , same same also in oracle .

At the end i think vertica is Competitive and probably more cheaper .

Sorry I can not provide comparative figures , however if you insist you may get it from your Vertical salesperson

Thanks